# Creating an access point with wpa_supplicant via dbus interface

Tags: linux, dbus, wpa-supplicant

I was told that it's possible to create an access point with wpa_supplicant over its dbus interface. All I found with a google is [this forum thread](http://hostap.shmoo.narkive.com/7fvRwSNJ/creating-an-access-point-with-wpa-supplicant-via-dbus-interface), which, despite having exact same title, isn't much informative to me.

Is it possible to do this via wpa_supplicant dbus interface and what exact steps does it take to create one with custom parameters (like frequency, etc.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all, I've found a way to launch access point with wpa_supplicant's dbus inteface. 
 Below is pretty self explanatory python code that's is trying to launch AP with the first interface (adapter) it have found.

```py
import dbus
import sys

ssid = "TEST_WPA_DBUS_HOTSPOT"
frequency = 2412

bus = dbus.SystemBus()
wpa_sup_obj = bus.get_object('fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1', '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1')
props_iface = dbus.Interface(wpa_sup_obj, "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")

interfaces = props_iface.Get('fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1', "Interfaces")

try:
    interface = interfaces[0]
except IndexError:
    sys.exit("No interfaces availible")


print "Creating ap with %s" % (interface)

interface_obj = bus.get_object('fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1', interface)
interface_interface_props = dbus.Interface(interface_obj, "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")
interface_interface = dbus.Interface(interface_obj, "fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface")
adapters_name = interface_interface_props.Get("fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface", "Ifname")

print "Interface's name is %s" % adapters_name


key_mgmt = "NONE"
args = dbus.Dictionary({
    'ssid': ssid,
    'key_mgmt': key_mgmt,
    'mode': 2,
    'frequency': frequency
    }, signature='sv')

netw = interface_interface.AddNetwork(args)
interface_interface.SelectNetwork(netw)


print "AP %s with frequency %i created with adapter %s" % ( ssid, frequency, adapters_name)
```

Note, that, after all, I've found wpa_supplicant not quite reliable for my needs (in my particular case, I wasn't able to launch 5GHz AP) and have switched to launching hostapd with different configuration files.

Comment: For those looking into this in the future, here is the link to the official DBUS API documentation: http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/dbus.html